# Can I do a jquery-tmpl each over object properties

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-templates

The template {{each}} directive works great for iterating over an array like this:

```
var myArray = ["a","b","c"];
```

I'm wondering if there is an equivalent for iterating over object properties, i.e.:

```
var myObj = {"propOne": "a", "propTwo": "b", "propThree": "c"};
```

I'd like a template that would let me output as

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>propOne</span><span>a</span></li>
  .... etc
```

For bonus points I'd like to use this template from KnockoutJS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually {{each}} will walk through properties on an object.  You can do something like this:

```
{{each(prop, val) myObj}}
      <li><span>${prop}</span> - <span>${val}</span></li>
{{/each}}
```

Here is a sample in Knockout: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/rpMsM/

If you really want to use the `foreach` option of the template binding, then the only real option is to map the object to an array of objects with key/value properties.  Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/rpMsM/1/

Comment: Giddy up, that is the bomb! =)

Answer (score 8):

You can also use this

```
{{each myObj}}
      <li><span>${$index}</span> - <span>${$value}</span></li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Need remove one symbol in a variable "$" .
`From ${$index} to ${index}`
It's helped for me.