# Get the name of an enum in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, enums, jquery-templates

I have the following jQuery template, which I want to display a drop down list for all the values in an enum. I can get the numeric value of the enum, but not the name. Is it possible to get the name? Below is the important snippets of the code - it displays 4 options in the drop down list, with the correct integer value for "value", but nothing for name. I've tried ${$key} as well, but I'm assuming I'm just missing some syntax?

Javascript enum:

```
var LayoutEnum = Object.freeze(
        {
            NotDefined: 0,
            OneTier: 1,
            TwoTier: 2,
            ThreeTier: 3,
        });
```

jQuery template:

```
<script id="Layout_template" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="control-group span4">
            <label>Layout:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <select id="LayoutControl">
                    {{each LayoutEnum }}
                        <option value="${$value}">${$name}</option>
                    {{/each}}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990585/can-i-do-a-jquery-tmpl-each-over-object-properties

Comment: Thank you! I've searched all over SO but didn't come across it.
Solved using <option value="${$value}">${$index}</option

Comment: Is there a way to set an option to selected in the template?

Comment: Just the normal html way. You would use an {{if}} to set the selected property.